# JavaCC simple example not working

Tags: javacc

I am trying javacc for the first time with a simple naive example which is not working. My BNF is as follows:

```
<exp>:= <num>"+"<num>
<num>:= <digit> | <digit><num>
<digit>:= [0-9]
```

Based on this BNF, I am writing the `SimpleAdd.jj` as follows:

```
    options
{
}
PARSER_BEGIN(SimpleAdd)
public class SimpleAdd
{
}
PARSER_END(SimpleAdd)
SKIP :
{
    " "
|   "\r"
|   "\t"
|   "\n"
}
TOKEN:
{
    < NUMBER: (["0"-"9"])+  >
}

int expr():
{
        int leftValue ;
        int rightValue ;
}
{
        leftValue = num()
        "+"
        rightValue = num()
        { return leftValue+rightValue; }
}

int num():
{
        Token t;
}
{
    t = <NUMBER> { return Integer.parseInt(t.toString()); }
}
```

using the above file, I am generating the java source classes. My main class is as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleAdd parser = new SimpleAdd(System.in);
        int x = parser.expr();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

When I am entering the expression via System.in, I am getting the following error:

```
11+11^D
Exception in thread "main" SimpleAddTest.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 0, column 0.
Was expecting:
    <NUMBER> ...

    at SimpleAddTest.SimpleAdd.generateParseException(SimpleAdd.java:200)
    at SimpleAddTest.SimpleAdd.jj_consume_token(SimpleAdd.java:138)
    at SimpleAddTest.SimpleAdd.num(SimpleAdd.java:16)
    at SimpleAddTest.SimpleAdd.expr(SimpleAdd.java:7)
    at SimpleAddTest.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Any hint to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** Note that this answer answers an earlier version of the question.

When a BNF production uses a nonterminal that returns a result, you can record that result in a variable.

First declare the variables in the declaration part of the BNF production

```
int expr():
{
    int leftValue ;
    int rightValue ;
}
{
```

Second, in the main body of the production, record the results in the variables.

```
    leftValue = num()
    "+"
    rightValue = num()
```

Finally, use the values of those variables to compute the result of this production.

```
    { return leftValue+rightValue; }
}
```

Comment: I have modified the jj file and use your answer but I am getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure you modified the return statement?  Did you rerun JavaCC and recompile the Java?

Comment: Yes, I did it, here is a github repo for the files, https://github.com/noorbakerally/SimpleAddJavaCC

Comment: I copied the .jj file out of your repository, compiled it, and ran it. It worked fine.

Comment: the mistake was because when I was entering the expression, I was pressing Ctrl+D for stop the System.in which was causing the error i don't why, when using Enter, it's ok

Comment: That explains why your original error way at column 0.  This behaviour might be OS dependent. On my Mac I had no problem pressing `1` `1` `+` `1` `1` `cntl-D` `return`.  This meant that System.in had 5 characters and the the end of file.  In any case the code you posted originally did have the error that my answer corrects.